# Meeting from shared calendar doesn't display attendee info

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange, calendar, exchange-2010, shared-mailbox

A user ("MG") is sent a meeting invitation from a shared calendar ("Project Calendar").
He can not see attendee's information in the Scheduling Assistant tab - including his own. Note this is opening the meeting from his own calendar:

[image]

He has PublishingEditor permissions to other attendee's calendars, and to the Project Calendar. 
If we open the same meeting on the Project Calendar itself (and not in MG's calendar), we can see all the information just fine.

[image]

This is not specific to one meeting - just the calendar, I'm not sure if this happens with other shared calendars.
This only affects this one user.
This is not outlook specific, as it affects his mobile devices.
Exchange 2010 ru14.

User2 does NOT have any special permissions to the Project Calendar (only can see free/busy), yet can see the attendee's availability from her own instance of the meeting on her calendar.

So, what's preventing MG from seeing this availability on his own calendar instance?